# How do I programmatically send encrypted emails in Outlook Express using Python?

Tags: c#, python, email, encryption, outlook

I'm a new programmer and I've reached the point where my lack of knowledge (of the C# and VBA language) and experience is preventing me from continuing with my program. I only know Python and all the documentation that I've tried digging into is in C# and VB.

My story: I'm working on a GUI that automates and manages specialized email operations for my company using Outlook Express 2016. I've figured out that win32com is the package to use, and I've figured out how to create and send basic emails, but I'm struggling to figure out how to send emails encrypted. My company uses the McAfee SaaS Email Encryption add-in found at: http://www.mcafee.com/us/downloads/saas/encrypted-from-microsoft-outlook-addin.aspx.

Note: the site doesn't specify that this add-in is supported in the 2016 version but it indeed works. Also, the built-in Outlook option to encrypt all emails is not viable because I need some emails to not be encrypted.

What I've garnered from another similar post is that I need to use the PropertyAccessor method:

```
mailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0xHHHHHHHH", x);
```

where `HHHHHHHH` is some hexadecimal code and `x` represents a state such as 0 = off. I tried digging into some property tag documentation but I'm having trouble understanding them.

Am I on the right track? There may be a completely different + easier way of doing this. I do realize a lot of my difficulty may be due to not knowing C#/VBA, but it would be highly appreciated if someone out there can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

1. First, you need a Secure Email certificate issued to the email address you want to use. 
   Let's say this is mymail.somecompany.com. Your cert should have this in the subject name and should be enabled for secure email.
2. Next, you need to programmatically get the certificate or load from a pfx file like 
     X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
     store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
     X509Certificate2Collection certs = store.Certificates;
     X509Certificate2 certificate = null;
     foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in certs)
     {
         if (cert.Subject.IndexOf("mymail@somecompany.com") >= 0)
         {
             certificate = cert;
             break;
         }
     }
3. Next, you need to have an entity that you want to sign and send. 
     string strbody = @"Content-Type: text/plain;charset=""iso-8859-1""
   Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

This is a test s/mime message";
This is where it gets a little not very intuitive since there is no programatic way of creating the email entity you want to send
Note the headers and a series of two \r\n before the entity body "this is a test s/mime" message begins

3. Next, you need to generate a signed envelope for this content

   byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strbody);
     ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(data);
     SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(content, false);
     CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, certificate);
     signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer);
     byte[] signedbytes = signedCms.Encode();
4. Now that you have the content you want to send is signed with the certificate of your choice you need to 
   create a mail message object and create an alternate view and add this to your alternate view collection

   MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
     msg.From = new MailAddress("");
     msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(""));
     msg.Subject = "test s/mime";

   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(signedbytes);
     AlternateView av = new AlternateView(ms, "application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=signed-data;name=smime.p7m");
     msg.AlternateViews.Add(av);
5. Now that you have the message prepared you can just send it
     SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtphost", 25);
     client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
     client.Send(msg);

This is a kind of hack at this time and requires some manual preparation of the entity body
you want to sign. I need to do some more research on this and find out if there is a better way of doing this.